# Why is doubleAction working only when it's handled in a view controller class?

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I have a view controller `MyViewController`:

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController {

    private let componentList = ComponentList()

    override func loadView() {
        componentList.createView(view)
        componentList.myTableView.doubleAction = #selector(doubleClickOnRow)
    }

    @objc func doubleClickOnRow() {
        print("some row clicked = \(componentList.myTableView.clickedRow)")
    }
}
```

This double click action works without problem. However, when I try to put this double click action inside `ComponentList`, it's not working (action function is not called):

```
class ComponentList: NSObject, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    let myTableView = NSTableView()

    override func createView(view: NSView) {
        let scrollView = NSScrollView()
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.documentView = myTableView            
        // set up some constraints, ignore here...
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self

        myTableView.doubleAction = #selector(doubleClickOnRow)
    }

    @objc func doubleClickOnRow() {
        print("some row clicked = \(myTableView.clickedRow)")

        // never being called, why is that?
    }
}
```

Why isn't the double action handling in `ComponentList` not working? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set both `target` and `doubleAction` to make it work with `ComponentList`

```
override func createView(view: NSView) {
    let scrollView = NSScrollView()
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.documentView = myTableView            
    // set up some constraints, ignore here...
    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self

    myTableView.doubleAction = #selector(doubleClickOnRow)
    myTableView.target = self // self here is ComponentList
}
```

Comment: Why does it work without a target in `MyViewController`?